# Mule java.lang.Exception: JDBC 4.0

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, mule

I'm having some issues when I try to run my program. it appears an error:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC 4.0
```

And I already add the library in my program, using the proper jre enviroment, but it keeps sending this error when they connect to my database. I tried every solution in stackoverflow for this issue and didn't work.

I verify that is the right sqljdbc4 too, I don't know what else to do.

Comment: There is an issu [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212037/sql-server-jdbc-exception). I hope this help you

Comment: It was the first answer I saw... didn't work neither.

Comment: You like also have the `sqljdbc.jar` on the classpath.

Comment: Tried already and keeps saying the same thing, I tried to use jdbc driver 4.0 and 6.0 sqljdc.jar and sqljdc4.jar

Comment: You need to have **only** sqljdbc4.jar on the classpath, if you also have sqljdbc.jar on the classpath, then the wrong driver gets loaded first.

Comment: Tried already, and is in the classpath, I'm using jdk 1.8 in preferences/installed jre. and using sqljdbc4.jar version sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100 in the classpath.